# v2.1 issue with Date Tabs in VB.NET application

Tags: docusignapi

I have my app setup with v2.0.6 right now and I can create Date Tabs.

In v2.1+ I cannot.

Now Signer.Tabs.DateTabs.Add(item as Date?) is asking for System.DateTime.Date? instead of DocuSign.eSign.Model.Date

And Signer.Tabs.DateTabs = New List(Of [Date]) no longer works, it wants Signer.Tabs.DateTabs = New List(Of Date?) which will not work.

Anyone know a fix or workaround? Right now I have to stay on v2.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug with the DocuSign.eSign.dll nuget package [v2.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4)

I have logged the following issue
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/135

---

## Update

This bug has been fixed with DocuSign.eSign.dll [v2.1.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.7)

Comment: Internal DocuSign bug id - DCM-1715

Comment: Thanks, I commented on another post there about the same issue back from May 2nd. Nothing has been updated yet.

Comment: DocuSign team is looking into this. Hopefully we get a fix out soon.

Comment: Nuget Package [v2.1.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.7) fixed this issue.

Comment: Thanks CodingDawg